# How to do data formatting using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am creating the tree chart for the web application, where i need to pass the data in specified format.
I have this data

```
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "jmd",
    "aname": "Asset123",
    "transformer_name": "IT1",
    "RMU": "rmu1",
    "feeder_name": "feeder",
    "pooling_station": "ppp1",
    "grid_name": "gggg1"
  }
]
```

expected result -

> ```
>  {
>          "name": "jmd",
>          "children": [
>            {
>              "name": "ppp1",
>              "children": [{
>                "name": "feeder",
>                "children": [{
>                  "name": "rmu1",
>                  "children": [{
>                    "name": "IT1",
>                    "children": [{
>                      "aname": "Asset123"
>                    }]
>                  }]
>                }]
>              }],
>            }
>  }
> ```

**How to do groupby multiple keys using lodash?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function (`recursiveGroupBy`) that receives an array of keys by the order you want to group by.

For each key, but the last, the function uses `_.groupBy()` on the key, and then maps all groups to objects with name (the group's name), and children. The children are generated by calling the `recursiveGroupBy` function and passing it rest of the keys, and the current group.

For the last key we map the array, and use `_.pick()` to create an object with the last key and it's value.

```js
const { groupBy, map, pick } = _

const recursiveGroupBy = ([key, ...restKeys], arr) => {  
  if(!restKeys.length) { // if last key
    return map(arr, o => pick(o, key)); // convert to an array of objects with the last key and values
  }
  
  const groups = groupBy(arr, key) // group by the current key

  return map(groups, (group, name) => ({ // generate the children's objects
    name,
    children: recursiveGroupBy(restKeys, group)
  }))
}

const arr = [{"name":"jmd","aname":"Asset123","transformer_name":"IT1","RMU":"rmu1","feeder_name":"feeder","pooling_station":"ppp1","grid_name":"gggg1"},{"name":"jmd","aname":"inv11","transformer_name":"itr11","RMU":"rmu11","feeder_name":"feeder3","pooling_station":"P2","grid_name":"sri"}]

const result = recursiveGroupBy(['name', 'pooling_station', 'feeder_name', 'RMU', 'transformer_name', 'aname'], arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `expected result` JSON appears to be corrupt. I inferred you wanted to end up with an array of objects built from nesting keys of the original object. You can achieve this by using recursion and lodash is not required:

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "jmd",
    "aname": "Asset123",
    "transformer_name": "IT1",
    "RMU": "rmu1",
    "feeder_name": "feeder",
    "pooling_station": "ppp1",
    "grid_name": "gggg1"
  },
  {
    "name": "jmd",
    "aname": "inv11",
    "transformer_name": "itr11",
    "RMU": "rmu11",
    "feeder_name": "feeder3",
    "pooling_station": "P2",
    "grid_name": "sri"
  }
];


const treeView = (arr, groupBy) => {
  return arr.map((el) => buildTree(
    el,
    groupBy ? [...groupBy] : Object.keys(el), // you can pass 'multiple grouping order' as an argument or it will group by all keys
    {}
  ));
}

const buildTree = (obj, keys, state) => {
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    return state;
  }
  state.name = obj[keys.shift()];
  return keys.length === 0 ? state : { ...state,
    children: [buildTree(obj, keys, state)]
  };
}

console.log(treeView(arr, ["name", "pooling_station", "feeder_name", "RMU", "transformer_name", "aname"]));
```

`treeView` function maps a recursive `buildTree` to each of it's objects. `buildTree` creates a new object by nesting following props until there are no more keys left.